# Animation with Sass and hover doesn't work?

Tags: css, animation, hover

I'm stuck on :hover doesn't work. I suspect the absolute and float position but don't have any clear idea. I'm a beginner user of Sass and the css animation. Any help ?

```css
    .menus {
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover >.box {
        transform: scale(0) translateX(300px);
        .check {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
    }
}
.box {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: green;
    transform: scale(1) translateX(0);
    transition: transform 330ms ease-in-out;
    .check {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
        right: 30%;
        top: 35%;
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
        transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="restaurants menus">
                    <div class="box"><img class="check" src="img/check24.png" alt="#"></div>

                    <h3>Citrus Squid Carpaccio</h3>
                    <p>with orange zest</p>
                    <img class="heart " src="img/heart-30.png" alt="#">
                </div>
```

Comment: Use the child combinator: &:hover > .box

Comment: that's it ... it works .. needs to be amended but it work. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here :

```
.menus {
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover + .box {
```

Your selector  `&:hover + .box` selects the `.box` elements that are siblings of `.menus`, and not children. You can use `&:hover .box` if you want to select all boxes children and grand children of `.menus`, or `&:hover>.box` to select direct `.box` children.

Here's a link with all the css selector that might be useful in the future: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've made the change you recommand but it still doesn't work.
I made some changes to my code so as to have the icone rolls inside the box while the latter spread out ... but I stil have only the icone rolls after reloading the browser. Take a look please. .... euuuh where can I post the new code? in the comment it tells me it's too long !!!

Comment: I've edited the original code and posted the new one.

Comment: that's it ... it works .. needs to be amended but it work. Thank you all